# Can I write a real async callback in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

This is a normal example to read a file:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('./gparted-live-0.18.0-2-i486.iso', function (err, data) {
  console.log(data.length);
});
console.log('All done.');
```

the code above outputs:

```
All done.
187695104
```

whereas this is my own version of a callback, I hope it could be async like the file reading code above, but it is not:

```
var f = function(cb) {
    cb();
};
f(function() {
    var i = 0;
    // Do some very long job.
    while(++i < (1<<30)) {}
    console.log('Cb comes back.')
});
console.log('All done.');
```

the code above outputs:

```
Cb comes back.
All done.
```

Up till now, it's clear that in the first version of the file reading code, `All done.` is always printed before the file is read. However, in the second my home brewed version of code, `All done.` is always waiting until the `very long job` is done.

So what on earth is the magic that makes `fs.readFile`'s callback an async call back while mine is not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var f = function(cb) {
    cb();
};
```

Is not async because it invokes `cb` immediately.

I think you want

```
var f = function(cb) {
   setImmediate(function(){ cb(); });
};
```

Comment: The new `setImmediate` is likely what you actually want (yes it's confusing, but they're slightly different) http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html

Answer (score 3):

In your example the while-loop is occupying the event-loop therefore the function call to `console.log('All done.')` is queued on the stack. When the event-loop becomes unblocked the subsequent function calls will be called in sequence.

In ***Mastering Node.js by Sandro Pasquali*** *- Chapter 2*, he discusses deferred execution and the event-loop in order to avoid the issue of the event-loop taking hold and blocking execution. I recommend reading that chapter in order to better understand this non-intuitive way of working in Node.js.

From ***Mastering Node.js***...

> Node processes JavaScript instructions using a single thread. Within
>   your JavaScript program no two operations will ever execute at exactly
>   the same moment, as might happen in a multithreaded environment.
>   Understanding this fact is essential to understanding how a Node
>   program, or process, is designed and runs.

The use of `setImmediate()` can remedy this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setImmediate()` to defer the execution of code until the next cycle of the event loop, which I think accomplishes what you want:

```
var f = function(cb) {
  cb();
};

f(function() {
  setImmediate(function() {
    var i = 0;
    // Do some very long job.
    while(++i < (1<<30)) {}
    console.log('Cb comes back.')
  });
});
console.log('All done.');
```

[The documentation for `setImmediate`](http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_arg) explains the difference between `process.nextTick` and `setImmediate` thusly:

> Immediates are queued in the order created, and are popped off the queue once per loop iteration. This is different from `process.nextTick` which will execute `process.maxTickDepth` queued callbacks per iteration. `setImmediate` will yield to the event loop after firing a queued callback to make sure I/O is not being starved. While order is preserved for execution, other I/O events may fire between any two scheduled immediate callbacks.

**Edit:** Update answer based on @generalhenry's comment.